# Error in SetValue in Firebase after Reauthenticating the user

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for chat in my application.

When i use setValue method to write at a node by Using childByAutoId it works fine. 
But when my AuthToken expires and I Authenticate the user again with my custom token, the message is saved on Firebase  but My .ChildAdded Observer fails to observe this change.

I am using Authenticate Using custom token method for Firebase.

Comment: to check change you need to add one more observer with `.ChildChanged`

Comment: please add your code in your question @Tina